# Ajax - using the script to load different 'events'

Tags: ajax

I am new to ajax, but currently have some code that will change a content area of the site once a link is clicked.
The trouble is, I want to load different content using different buttons, but the current code is only allowing me to link to one file/page.

```
  <script>
    function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("centreCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../home/indexFav.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

You can see in the above script that when i link to the script the ajax will always direct to '../home/indexFav.php'.

I want to use different links to load different content. How can this be done?

Here's my html:

```
<div class="" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Everyone</div>
<div class="" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Favourites Only</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can add an "argument" to the AJAX function which you can then call with differing values. Javascript below:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("centreCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","../home/" + pageName + ".php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Then your html could/would be something like this:

```
    <div class="" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone')">Everyone</div>
    <div class="" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexFav')">Favourites Only</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional argument to your `loadXMLDOC` function which takes the URL to load. e.g.:

```
function loadXMLDoc(url) {
  ...
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Then change your `onclick` methods:

```
<div class="" onclick="loadXMLDoc('../home/indexFav.php')">Everyone</div>
<div class="" onclick="loadXMLDoc('../home/indexAll.php')">Favourites Only</div>
```